# Оптимизация запроса mysql (долгое выполнение)

Tags: mysql, sql, оптимизация-запросов

Помогите оптимизировать запрос (выполняется 14 сек):

```
SELECT `task`.*
FROM `task`
         LEFT JOIN `user` `ru` ON `task`.`responsible_id` = `ru`.`id`
WHERE ((`task`.`created_by` NOT IN (SELECT `user_id`
                                    FROM `rbac_auth_assignment`
                                    WHERE `item_name` IN
                                          ('Лид-менеджер', 'Сотрудник call-центра', 'Руководитель call-центра'))) OR
       (`task`.`responsible_id` NOT IN (SELECT `user_id`
                                        FROM `rbac_auth_assignment`
                                        WHERE `item_name` IN
                                              ('Лид-менеджер', 'Сотрудник call-центра', 'Руководитель call-центра'))))
  AND ((`task`.`status` IN (1, 2)) AND (`task`.`deleted` = 0) AND (`ru`.`filial_id` = 106))
ORDER BY `end_date` DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Если удалить сортировку **ORDER BY `end_date` DESC** - запрос выполнится за ~0.5 сек

EXPLAIN первоначального запроса:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | ru | NULL | ref | PRIMARY,fk_user_filial1_idx | fk_user_filial1_idx | 5 | const | 430 | 100 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 1 | PRIMARY | task | NULL | ref | fk_task_user1_idx,idx-task-responsible_id | fk_task_user1_idx | 5 | admin_perk_test.ru.id | 324 | 2 | Using where |
| 3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | rbac_auth_assignment | NULL | range | PRIMARY,idx_rbac_auth_assignment_user_id | PRIMARY | 194 | NULL | 127 | 100 | Using where; Using index |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | rbac_auth_assignment | NULL | range | PRIMARY,idx_rbac_auth_assignment_user_id | PRIMARY | 194 | NULL | 127 | 10 | Using where; Using index |

Таблица task (850 000 записей):

```
create table task
(
    id             int auto_increment
        primary key,
    title          text                 null,
    description    text                 null,
    category_id    int        default 0 not null,
    responsible_id int                  null,
    a_deal_id      int                  null,
    order_id       int                  null,
    leads_id       int                  null,
    created_at     int                  not null,
    created_by     int                  not null,
    updated_at     int                  null,
    updated_by     int                  null,
    date_until     int                  null,
    end_date       int                  null,
    status         smallint   default 0 not null,
    notified       tinyint(1) default 0 not null,
    deleted        tinyint(1) default 0 null,
    task_type_id   int                  null,
    comment        text                 null,
    start_date     int                  null,
    ag_lead_id     int                  null,
    constraint `fk-task-ag_lead_id`
        foreign key (ag_lead_id) references leads (id)
            on update cascade,
    constraint `fk-task-responsible_id`
        foreign key (responsible_id) references user (id)
            on update cascade,
    constraint fk_task_a_deal1
        foreign key (a_deal_id) references a_deal (id)
            on update cascade on delete cascade,
    constraint fk_task_leads1
        foreign key (leads_id) references leads (id),
    constraint fk_task_order1
        foreign key (order_id) references `order` (id),
    constraint fk_task_spr_operation_category1
        foreign key (category_id) references spr_operation_category (id),
    constraint fk_task_user1
        foreign key (responsible_id) references user (id)
            on update cascade,
    constraint fk_task_user2
        foreign key (created_by) references user (id)
            on update cascade,
    constraint fk_task_user3
        foreign key (updated_by) references user (id)
            on update cascade
)
    charset = utf8;

create index fk_task_a_deal1_idx
    on task (a_deal_id);

create index fk_task_leads1_idx
    on task (leads_id);

create index fk_task_order1_idx
    on task (order_id);

create index fk_task_spr_operation_category1_idx
    on task (category_id);

create index fk_task_user1_idx
    on task (responsible_id);

create index fk_task_user2_idx
    on task (created_by);

create index fk_task_user3_idx
    on task (updated_by);

create index `idx-task-ag_lead_id`
    on task (ag_lead_id);

create index `idx-task-responsible_id`
    on task (responsible_id);

create index `idx_task-date_until-start_date`
    on task (date_until, start_date);

create index idx_task_category_id_status_deleted_start_date_index
    on task (category_id, status, deleted, start_date);

create index temp_task_end_date_index
    on task (end_date);
```

Таблица user (13 000 записей):

```
create table user
(
    id                   int auto_increment
        primary key,
    username             varchar(32)            null,
    auth_key             varchar(32)            not null,
    access_token         varchar(40)            not null,
    password_hash        varchar(255)           not null,
    oauth_client         varchar(255)           null,
    oauth_client_user_id varchar(255)           null,
    email                varchar(255)           not null,
    telegram             int                    null,
    status               smallint    default 2  not null,
    created_at           int                    null,
    updated_at           int                    null,
    logged_at            int                    null,
    dismissal_at         int                    null comment 'Дата увольнения',
    password_reset_token varchar(255)           null,
    percent              float                  null,
    ruk                  int                    null,
    role                 varchar(255)           null,
    start                date                   null,
    otdel                varchar(255)           null,
    phone                varchar(50) default '' null,
    vk_id                varchar(100)           null,
    filial_id            int                    null,
    telegram_username    varchar(100)           null,
    time_zone            tinyint(3)  default 0  not null,
    mobile_password_hash varchar(255)           null,
    constraint fk_user_filial1
        foreign key (filial_id) references filial (id)
)
    collate = utf8_unicode_ci;

create index fk_user_filial1_idx
    on user (filial_id);

create index `idx-user-status`
    on user (status);
```

Таблица rbac_auth_assignment (20 000 записей):

```
create table rbac_auth_assignment
(
    item_name  varchar(64) not null,
    user_id    varchar(64) not null,
    created_at int         null,
    primary key (item_name, user_id),
    constraint rbac_auth_assignment_ibfk_1
        foreign key (item_name) references rbac_auth_item (name)
            on update cascade on delete cascade
)
    collate = utf8_unicode_ci;

create index idx_rbac_auth_assignment_user_id
    on rbac_auth_assignment (user_id);
```

**UPD 1:**

Версия mysql: 8.0.25-15

Преобразовал запрос - LEFT JOIN заменил на INNER JOIN, NOT IN переписал на NOT EXISTS

```
SELECT `task`.*
FROM `task`
         INNER JOIN `user` `ru` ON `task`.`responsible_id` = `ru`.`id`
WHERE ((NOT EXISTS(SELECT `user_id`
                   FROM `rbac_auth_assignment`
                   WHERE `item_name` IN
                         ('Лид-менеджер', 'Сотрудник call-центра', 'Руководитель call-центра')
                     AND task.created_by = cast(`rbac_auth_assignment`.`user_id` as unsigned))
           ) OR
       (NOT EXISTS(SELECT `user_id`
                   FROM `rbac_auth_assignment`
                   WHERE `item_name` IN
                         ('Лид-менеджер', 'Сотрудник call-центра', 'Руководитель call-центра')
                     AND task.responsible_id = cast(rbac_auth_assignment.user_id as unsigned))))
  AND ((`task`.`status` IN (1, 2)) AND (`task`.`deleted` = 0) AND (`ru`.`filial_id` = 106))
ORDER BY `end_date` DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Время выполнения не изменилось, EXPLAIN также практически не изменился

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | ru | NULL | ref | PRIMARY,fk_user_filial1_idx | fk_user_filial1_idx | 5 | const | 430 | 100 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 1 | PRIMARY | task | NULL | ref | fk_task_user1_idx,idx-task-responsible_id | fk_task_user1_idx | 5 | admin_perk_test.ru.id | 324 | 2 | Using where |
| 3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | rbac_auth_assignment | NULL | range | PRIMARY,idx_rbac_auth_assignment_user_id | PRIMARY | 194 | NULL | 127 | 100 | Using where; Using index |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | rbac_auth_assignment | NULL | range | PRIMARY,idx_rbac_auth_assignment_user_id | PRIMARY | 194 | NULL | 127 | 10 | Using where; Using index |

Comment: Для начала замените `LEFT JOIN user` на INNER JOIN - всё равно ```AND (`ru`.`filial_id` = 106)``` это делает неявно.

Comment: Что же до оптимизации - надо избавляться от NOT IN и переписывать на NOT EXISTS. Кстати, неплохо бы сказать, какая точно версия MySQL используется.

Comment: @Akina, внёс эти изменения, добавил их в вопрос, результатов не принесло.

Comment: попробуйте сотворить явный индекс для `end_date`, а то вот это `create index temp_task_end_date_index
    on task (end_date);` судя по explane не востребовано.

Comment: @Zombotron не понял, что значит "сотворить явный индекс для end_date" и чем это отличается от уже существующего temp_task_end_date_index?

Comment: `temp_task_end_date_index` я не наблюдаю в выдаче explane, значит он не используется...  Просто попробуйте. )

Comment: @Zombotron добавил в запрос `FORCE INDEX (\`temp_task_end_date_index\`)` - запрос стал выполняться практически мгновенно. Как можно объяснить - почему этого индекса нет в **possible_keys**?

Comment: Я не помню, как это правильно обзывается, но примерно суть в том, что вы создаете индекс "неявно". Т.е. он  где-то есть, но с  другим именем и внутренний оптимизатор его просто не видит.. Если что, это мое интуитивное понимание. Буквоедством я заниматься не собираюсь, искать все нюансы правильного именования и точных особенностей работы тоже. Во-первых, это не особо улучшит понимание, во-вторых, забуду все равно. ) Про force index я забыл. обычно мне хватает ALTER TABLE tbl ADD INDEX (col) даже для огромных таблиц.

Comment: И еще, всегда пользуюсь правилом "если больше 2-х join'ов (3-х таблиц) в запросе, значит с архитектурой приложения что-то не то".